# What is the non-recursive function of the following recursive function?

Tags: recursion, lisp

```
(defun filter-numbers-rec (inlist)
  "This function filters out non-numbers from its input list and returns
the result, a list of numbers"
  (cond
    ((not (listp inlist))
     (princ "Argument must be a list")
     (terpri)
     ())
    ((null inlist)
     ())
    ((not (numberp (car inlist)))
     (filter-numbers-rec (cdr inlist)))
    (t
     (cons (car inlist)
           (filter-numbers-rec (cdr inlist))))))
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, the description of what the function does is that you want to *remove* each thing from the the list *if* it is *not* a number, so a good candidate here is [`remove-if-not`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rm_rm.htm%27), which you would use as follows:

```
(remove-if-not 'numberp '(1 a 2 b 3 c #\x (y 4)))
;=> (1 2 3)
```

If, for some reason, you want to write this in a way that (might) not use recursion, you could use [`do`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_do_do.htm):

```
(do ((list '(1 a 2 b 3 c #\x (y 4)) (rest list))
     (result '()))
    ((endp list) (nreverse result))
  (when (numberp (car list))
    (push (car list) result)))
;=> (1 2 3)
```

If you don't like the wordiness of `do`, you can use `loop`:

```
(loop :for x :in '(1 a 2 b 3 c #\x (y 4))
   :when (numberp x)
   :collect x)
;=> (1 2 3)
```